# Passing an ArrayList of address into MapActivity to Display Multiple location into map (android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the list of the Address(not Lat,Lng) which is on the other activity. Now I want to pass those address into my MapActivity via Intent extras and geocode it. How can I do this?

Below is my address data which is in my Listview activity

```
viewHolder.address.setText(row[4]);//Read from CSV file
```

Comment: You will have to reverse geocode the address into lat/lng. And then plot them on the map as markers. Have a look at the Geocoder class.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data to activity using list or map and use following code to get the lat long from address

```
public void getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

   Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
   List<Address> address;
   GeoPoint p1 = null;

   try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address==null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address location=address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("TAG","Lat = "+location.getLatitude())
    Log.i("TAG","Long = "+location.getLongitude())
    }
}
```

Also Check This [Geocoding Example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/554371/Android/Mobile/longitude-latitude-address)

Comment: Ty for that . But how can I pass the address ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class GeoData {
        private String address,lat,lng;
        public GeoData() {
             this("", "0", "0");
        }

    public GeoData(String address, String lat, String lng) {
        this.address = address;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

Create below methods in your activity.

```
private GeoData getAddresesFronJson(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    if (jsonObj == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONArray resultJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        ArrayList<GeoData> resultList = new ArrayList<GeoData>(
                resultJsonArray.length());
        JSONObject locationObject = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            GeoData data = new GeoData();
            data.setAddress(resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                    "formatted_address"));
            locationObject = resultJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

            data.setLat(locationObject.getString("lat"));

            data.setLng(locationObject.getString("lng"));

            return data;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONObject", "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }
    return null;
}




private void computeAddress(String address) {
    address = address.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    String apiKey = "YOUR PROJECT API KEY(Genarate from google console))";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
            + address + "&key=" + apiKey;
    // Log.i("googleapis--url:", url.toString());

    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    GeoData geoData = getAddresesFronJson(jsonObject);
                    if (geoData == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // Use this geoData object
                }

            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                }
            });
}
```

Just use computeAddress(String address) method for getting the Geocode object.
By using Geocode you can display the address markers in the map.